# colorbox with height same as image height

Tags: pdftex, header-footer

What I expect is to get a color box or a bar in the footer section with an image
[image]

What I am getting is a color bar with some extra space around the image
[image]

How can I get a color box to have the same height as the included image without any space added at the top or bottom of the image?

This is the code that I am currently using.

`\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\hspace*{-0.2\headwidth}\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{gray}{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\makebox[\dimexpr0.2\headwidth-2\fboxsep][c]{%
  \strut \includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{./LogoShort}}}%
  \colorbox{gray}{\makebox[\dimexpr0.98\headwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\strut ORGGroup}}%
  \colorbox{gray}{\makebox[\dimexpr0.22\headwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\strut \thepage}}}`

Comment: Add `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` to your settings; perhaps directly in the footer. It would be more convenient to help you if you could show us some code that would replicate your current behaviour.

Comment: I already have used the `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`. However it simply removes the upper spacing, the lower spacing still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
\strut \includegraphics
```

A `\strut` has the maximum height *and depth* of text at the current font size, so you are boxing something that descends below the image which sits on the baseline. Just remove the `\strut`.